# User input populating an array

Tags: java, arrays

How can I create a 20-element integer array and let the user populate it?

I tried the following:

```
    import java.util.*;

    class Selection{
    public static void main(String[] args){

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int a [] = new int [x];
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    while(a.length<21){
        System.out.print("Enter element number  " + (y+1) + " : ");
        x = in.nextInt();
        y++;
    }

    System.out.println(a);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the array to be size 20:

```
int[] a = new int[20];
```

Then, in a for loop based on the length of the array, let the user enter numbers:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter element number  " + i + " : ");
    a[i] = in.nextInt();
}
```

Here is a revision of your class that shows how to properly declare, fill, and print the array:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Selection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[20];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter element number  " + i + " : ");
            a[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        // if you want to display the array after filling, there are 2 standard ways
        for (int element : a) {
            System.out.println(element); // displays each on a new line
        }

        // or, using Arrays.toString() (from the java.util package)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you can tell me how to transform it into descending order and print it? I am struggling so hard with this

Comment: The array needs to store ordered values? Or you need to print the array in reverse order?

Comment: I need to print it in descending order. For example, if the user populated it with 5,4,7,2,9  I should print it as 9,7,5,4,2 . I can do it in normal order by using selecting sort, but I cant do it in descending order

Comment: Once it is sorted, use a for loop that starts at the last-element in the array and decrements until it reaches the first element (0). Then, print each value for each iteration of the loop. I'll give you a chance to figure it out on your own first, then let me know if you need me to post some code.

Comment: I got it!! Cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

Before Populated array u have to set array size. in you case you need to set array set up to 20.

```
int[] a = new int[20];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things you're missing. You want to initialize `int[] a` with a size of 20 like so `int[] a = new int[20]`. You need to place `int a[]` into your `while` loop so that you can store the integers.

Looks like you're iterating with `y`, so `y` will work as our element index into which we will store the `int` that the user inputs. Lastly, you can't print out `int[] a` like that, you need to either iterate through it and print each value at each index yourself, or use the `Arrays.toString()` utility which can be accessed by placing `import java.util.Arrays;` at the top of your file along with your other imports. Putting this all together, your main method should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int a[] = new int[20];
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (y < a.length) {
        System.out.print("Enter element number  " + (y + 1) + " : ");
        x = in.nextInt();
        a[y] = x;
        y++;
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```